# different output on local michine when creating a Map

Tags: erlang, elixir

I was reading the doc of elixir and executing the related codes, everything was fine until [this part](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/keywords-and-maps.html#maps). This part says:

```
iex> map = %{:a => 1, 2 => :b}
%{2 => :b, :a => 1}
iex> map[:a]
1
iex> map[2]
:b
```

But if i do the same in my laptop i get an error:

```
iex(1)> map = %{:a => 1, 2 => :b}
** (SyntaxError) iex:1: invalid token: %{:a => 1, 2 => :b}
```

What am i doing wrong?? Any idea?

```
Elixir version: Elixir 0.10.3
Erlang version: rlang/OTP 17 [erts-6.0] [source-07b8f44] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false] [dtrace]
```

Comment: I'm surprised Elixir version 0.10.3 works with Erlang R17 at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an outdated Elixir version on your laptop (0.10.3). Maps are introduced in version 0.13.0

Comment: Thanks, i upgraded elixir but I forgot to update the path so i was using the old version. Now everything is working fine.